# Default route (controller/action) and links of css/js doesn't work cakephp

Tags: apache, cakephp

After extracting the cake 2.5.2 (on Linux) to the directory `/var/www/html/teste` when accessing the url `http://localhost/teste` it correctly loads the contents of the controller `pages` and action `display` as from `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

But when trying to access the controller directly through url:

`http://localhost/teste/pages/display` I have the return of 404 Page not found.

Otherwise, the files `css/js/img` the webroot folder (not being included for the url generated) are not loaded.

Url generated that returns file not found:

```
http://localhost/teste/css/cake.generic.css
```

Url to access the file correctly:

```
http://localhost/teste/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css
```

My solution to the files css/js/img was the following, I changed the form to call the file.

Standard form used:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

New form:

```
echo $this->Html->css('/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css');
```

In short, I think the error might actually be in apache or something, but do not know exactly how can I validate that part.

My solution to the css / js / img so is it correct? Because I think that was to work as the example I downloaded the version of the cake properly.

If they need more information just tell me, thanks.

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a symptom of an environment with mod_rewrite disabled.

If you use Ubuntu, just type:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

In your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf find the a block similar to this one:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And replace the line

```
    AllowOverride None
```

With

```
    AllowOverride All
```

And finally, restart your apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```